# How to intergrate cas restful in Web application?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I'm using CAS build SSO, I want to  implement login/logout by using CAS RESTful API in my own Web Application.

and the api like this `http://sso.cvs.cn:9990/cas-server-webapp/v1/tickets`
i test it by test case, and it succesful. here is the code:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String username = "123";
    String password = "123";
    validateFromCAS(username, password);
}

public static boolean validateFromCAS(String username, String password) throws Exception {

    String url = "http://sso.cvs.cn:9990/cas-server-webapp/v1/tickets";
    try {
        HttpURLConnection hsu = (HttpURLConnection) openConn(url);
        String s = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
        s += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println(s);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(hsu.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(out);
        bwr.write(s);
        bwr.flush();
        bwr.close();
        out.close();

        String tgt = hsu.getHeaderField("location");
        System.out.println(hsu.getResponseCode());
        if (tgt != null && hsu.getResponseCode() == 201) {
            System.out.println(tgt);

            System.out.println("Tgt is : " + tgt.substring(tgt.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            tgt = tgt.substring(tgt.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            bwr.close();
            closeConn(hsu);

            String serviceURL = "http://sso.cvs.cn:7070/cas-simple-site-alpha/";
            String encodedServiceURL = URLEncoder.encode("service", "utf-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(serviceURL, "utf-8");
            System.out.println("Service url is : " + encodedServiceURL);

            String myURL = url + "/" + tgt;
            System.out.println(myURL);
            hsu = (HttpURLConnection) openConn(myURL);
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(hsu.getOutputStream());
            bwr = new BufferedWriter(out);
            bwr.write(encodedServiceURL);
            bwr.flush();
            bwr.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Response code is:  " + hsu.getResponseCode());
            BufferedReader isr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hsu.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            System.out.println(hsu.getResponseCode());
            while ((line = isr.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            isr.close();
            hsu.disconnect();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
        throw mue;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        throw ioe;
    }
}
```

but how i can use the api in my web application?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your question is how the api would be usefull for you in general.

So if this is the case, with restful api enabled on cas, when a user gets authenticated by CAS server, he would be allowed to access other applications (cas enabled services) which are configured to have SSO with the same CAS server. Also you can do requests for tickets with POST as the [documentation](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/restful+api) suggests.

Also another reason is that applications need to programmatically access CAS. Say one casified application can invoke other casified application’s REST APIs on behalf of an authenticated user. For this purpose CAS Rest protocol will do the job

Comment: first, if without restful api, just use original cas-server and cas-client. it's succesful. include login page and redirect.
second, with restful api, in the client app, the login page is customized, and how can i call the restful login api by the login page, and shuold i  programmatically write the TGT in the cookie?

Comment: @JJ_Jacob you can pass the username and password that you want as parameters to a httpclient and perform a POST request to the http://yourip/cas/v1/tickets. The successfull response will be the tgt. You can find more info to the link that i posted to the answer